# Error calculating shortest path with Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am using Networkx library to calculate the shortest path in a graph I build. It works almost all of the time but we found out there is a bug occuring when we try to find the path between two edges. 
When we call the "has_path()" function it says there is a path between those edges but the method only display a portion of the path.
For instance we have the path: [A,B,C,D,E,F] -> path from A to F.
but the method only returns: [A,B,C,D]. In order to troubleshoot I tried then to search the path between D and F to see if I would get the other portion of the path but it gives an error:

> > w = succ[path[-1]]
> >     IndexError: list index out of range
> >     So it basically fails using the shortest_path method.. any clues?

This is my code for the building of the graph and the calculation of the path.

```
#Add the Nodes to the graph
    addNodes(grouplist, crossGraph)

    df = getData(groupNum, cnxn)
    for row in df.itertuples():
      # print("Row: " + str(row))
      crossGraph.add_edge(row[1], row[2])
    path = []
    # print(crossGraph.size())
    path = nx.shortest_path(crossGraph, source = opk, target = apk)
```

path size: 5
source: STMST1S14PHR - destination: ONSNBA3N200SDR2G 
path: ['STMST1S14PHR', 'NSCLM22675MRXADJ!A', 'MXMMAX17542GATBP!B', 'NSCLM2672MXADJNOPB', 'MXMMAX5080ATEPLUST', 'NSCLM2594MXADJNOPB'] 
this is what I get when I try to find the path between source and destination.
I tried then to calculate the path between 'NSCLM2594MXADJNOPB' and 'ONSNBA3N200SDR2G' to see if I could get the other portion of the path but I got this:
path size: 6
source: NSCLM2594MXADJNOPB - destination: ONSNBA3N200SDR2G
path: ['ITSISL3178EIUZ', 'TIDSN65HVD75DGK', 'ITSISL4485EIBZ', 'TIDSN65LBC176AD', 'STMST485ABDR', 'TISSN75HVD10DR', 'ONSNBA3N200SDR2G']

at last I tried to find the path between 'NSCLM2594MXADJNOPB' and 'ITSISL3178EIUZ' but then I get an error:

File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\shortest_paths\generic.py", line 170, in shortest_path
    paths = nx.bidirectional_shortest_path(G, source, target)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\shortest_paths\unweighted.py", line 237, in bidirectional_shortest_path
    w = succ[path[-1]]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: And how do you know there is a path? From the edges you feed the graph? Can we see a minimal example? Also please share  what `nx.has_path(G, 'A', 'F')` and `nx.shortest_path(G, 'A', 'F')` (or between the corresponding nodes) is giving  you

Comment: Or seing you're using a dataframe, perhaps share a sample of that

Comment: Please update  with question with some of these examples, and the result you get from running these tests. Right now its hard to help with the info you've provided so far

Comment: I uploaded the whole troubleshooting process I've done

Comment: please add a minimal example code for testing

Comment: I dont know how to give you something testable, it's a big dataframe and it's working for all the path I look for but for this.. I dont know how to replicate this fault without the whole dataframe. Also it is something inside networkx library failing.. that's the weird thing

Comment: When you say: "I tried then to search the path between D and F", can you give the exact command you used?  And then give the entire error message - we need to see the line numbers and everything.

Comment: I have a web app from where I give the source and the destination. The app takes those params and calculates the shortest_path between those edges. The error is thrown by the shortest_path calculation.
The line of code giving the error is this:
>path = nx.shortest_path(crossGraph, source = opk, target = apk)

and as you can see from the error output the problem is inside the networkx lib

Comment: But you don't get any more of an error message than `w = succ[path[-1]] IndexError: list index out of range`?

Comment: exactly, I only get that thing. It should be an error during the calculation of the path inside the lib but I dont get what the problem could be. 
If the path doesnt exist it should just return an empty list, if the path exists it should return a list.. that error shouldnt show up I guess